# Let R be the relation on the set of ordered pairs of positive integers, Z+ × Z+, such that (a, b)R(c, d) if and only if ad = bc.

Tags: equivalence-relations

(For instance, (2, 4)R(6, 12) since 2·12 = 4·6.) Show that R is an equivalence relation.

I was tasked to show that the sets is an equivalence relation if the three conditions Reflexive, symmetric and transitive is shown valid, However I faced difficulties when showing transitive?

I really need hints.
Thanks.

Comment: What difficulties did you face? What did you try to do to prove that the relation is transitive, and where did it go wrong?

Comment: well I just want to show that is transitive: aRb and bRc then aRc, if a is related to be and b is related to c then a related to c. I started ad=bc and bc=? thats where I have trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $(a,b)R(c,d)$ and $(c,d)R(e,f).$ We see that this implies that
$$ad = bc \wedge cf = de.$$
We want to show that
$$af = be.$$
Given that $b \neq 0.$ We see that
$$\frac{ad}{b} = c \implies \frac{adf}{b} = de.$$
$$\implies adf = bde.$$
Given taht $d \neq 0$, We see that
$$af = be \implies (a,b)R(e,f).$$
And we have thus proved transitivity.